# Integrating GIT repository with Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

When I am trying to give the Git URL in Jenkins source code management, I am getting this error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/shivnathr/DevOPS1 HEAD
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Now Im getting this error message.                                                        
 Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin ls-remote -h https://github.com/userxyz/DEVOPS2.git HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Jenkins is running as your account, and not as a service with a technical account.

That way, Jenkins will benefit from the same configuration as your account.

But first, check if you can, with your account, in a simple CMD shell session, execute that same command successfully:

```
 git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/shivnathr/DevOPS1 HEAD
```

Comment: Yes,Jenkins is running on my account and executed the mentioned command successfully.But still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure this in Jenkins, it gives this error. But if you ignore this error, does it then work for the build? Have you configured git tools in Jenkins? I am not sure if having git in the path for the user running Jenkins will work (it might), but if you configure a git tool, it should use the first tool in the list to find git. BUT, if the first tool is set to auto-install, then this problem can occur. Make sure the first git tool is just pointing to an installation on the machine. I believe this is a bug. I found this on one of my installations, but I have yet to open an issue for it.

Comment: Its not working for build when ignoring the error.Yes I configured git tools in Jenkins.still working on to find a solution.

Comment: its working for the build(build says "failed to determine(log)") now even with the error. but the console output says Failure and ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'